# Is there any list or reference for maximum fast charging values/wattages of Apple devices?

Tags: macos, ios, battery, charging

From what I understand, many of Apple’s iOS (and iPad OS) capable devices are capable of fast charging since the iPhone 6 (6s?) was released. And nowadays, all MacBooks (MacBook, MacBook Pro and MacBook Air) are all capable of fast charging.

But no matter what specs I look at — Apple or even third party websites like [EveryMac](https://everymac.com) — I can only seem to get the broadest and most basic power specs; such as basic AC requirements and battery life data. I can’t seem to find any fast charging values and data.

## Is there a source of info on what the fast charge rates (wired and wireless) and capabilities are for modern Apple devices?

This question is spurred by the fact that:

- I have an iPhone 8 that only seems to charge at an 11-12W fast charging rate even when connected to higher wattage chargers via USB C. Confirmed using an inline voltage tester using official Apple USB to Lightning cables (USB A and USB C).
- But I also have a MacBook Air (2019) that comes with a 30W charger but can fast charge at 45W when a capable charger is connected.
- Similar with an iPad Mini (2019) that came with a 12W charger but can charge at 18W.

I like the fact I have devices that can fast charge, but it would be nice to know — at a glance and without per-device testing — what rate devices can be fast charged at.

Comment: You may already know this, but the rate at which iOS (and now iPadOS) devices charge at will also depend on whether or not it's wirelessly charging or connected via cable, and also their current state of charge. For example, an iPhone will charge at a faster rate up until it gets to an 80% charge level, and then it'll charge at a slower rate. And, with iOS 13 about to launch, that's also going to make some changes to the charging process.

Comment: Yeah, Apple doesn't make this easy to find. When I have time I'll see what I can dig up, because I have seen bits and pieces on different Apple pages, as well as other credible sources. That said, I certainly don't recall ever seeing a central resource that contains all the info. :(

Comment: On this page there are charts with logic used by iPhone for chargers with different power output 20W and 30W for example. https://www.inviolabs.com/blogs/news/iphone-11-charging-test-which-usb-pd-charger-is-better

Comment: Even though Apple does not provide this information, we can probably figure it out if enough people contribute.  One fact that helps is, that the maximum charge wattage of devices does not seem to vary from year to year.  You already have the data for a few devices; allow me to add a few more to the list.  MacBook Pro 13-inch, maximum = 65W; MacBook Pro 15-inch, maximum = 85W; MacBook Pro 16-inch, maximum = 96W.    While the Voltage varies depending on the model, the Wattage does not seem to depend on the year of manufacture (e.g. MacBook Air's charge at 45W at least as far back as Mid-2011).